# Change colors of stacked bar plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to change the colors of my stacked bar plot but I keep getting an error message

As I need specific colors in my stacked bar plot to match with another graph I set up the color vector: `colori` with RGB values which I then convert into values between 0 and 1 after creating the figuer I want to change colors of the 15 stacked bars like this:

```
 for i = 1:15
    barSNE(i,:).FaceColor = colori(i);
 end
```

here a bit mor of the code:

```
...

colori =  [139,0,0
    255,160,122;
    255,69,0;
    255,165,0;
    255,215,0;
    154,205,50;
    34,139,34;
    50,205,50;
    255,182,193;
    106,90,205;
    139,0,139;
    32,178,170;
    199,21,133;
    30,144,255;
    0,0,205];
colori = colori ./ 255;   

ctMeansT = ctMeans.';

figure(2)
barSNE = bar(ctMeansT, 'stacked');

 for i = 1:15
    barSNE(i,:).FaceColor = colori(i);
 end
```

However, I get following Error message:

> ```
> Structure assignment to non-structure object.
>
> Error in viSNE_stacked_bar_plot (line 41)
>      barSNE(i,:).FaceColor = colori(i);
> ```

Colors in the figuere are not changed as expected

Answer (score 0):

Your did a wrong indexing of your arrays `barSNE` and `colori`. If I run the code as you posted it above and check the size of both arrays I get

```
>> size(barSNE)

ans =

    1    15

>> size(colori)

ans =

    15     3
```

So `barSNE` is a one-dimensional array, while `colori` is a matrix of size 15 x 3. However, you tread it in your code vice versa given your index notation. E.g. If you do `colori(i)` you do not get the first RGB triplet as desired, but the first single value of the array `colori` (in your case 139/256 = 0.5451).

Change the indexing within the loop as follows

```
for i = 1:15
    barSNE(i).FaceColor = colori(i,:);
end
```

and it works. As an example with random numbers for `ctMeans` (since you haven't provided your original data) I get a bar chart like this

[image]